# SWT - current platform in

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I've got two questions:

1. How I can to know the type of the current platform in code? Is it Mac or Linux or Windows.
2. Is there something in SWT?

Comment: What do you need that information for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
String platform = SWT.getPlatform();
```

which returns "win32", "motif", "gtk", "photon", "carbon", "cocoa", "wpf" ...

It is rare to actually need to use this.

Comment: TNX!
Only one question more:
Is result is cocoa for last macos?


I will fix the code editor code:
<code>
// handle "Ctrl+Z" : undo
tw.addKeyListener(new KeyStrokeAdapter("Ctrl+z") {
@Override
protected void onAction() {
 getUndoManager().undo();
 }
});
<code>

end for mac I mast replace the Ctrl+Z to cmd+z

Comment: 64 bit SWT on Mac OS X is "cocoa". Eclipse key bindings support `M1` for Cmd on Macs and Ctrl elsewhere - but I don't know what your `KeyStrokeAdapter` is so I don't know if it will work here.